# WebAPI DI Framework that understands HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I am looking for a DI framework that can satisfy this scenario:

Every Controller has a constructor like this

```
public ThisController( ThatRepository repo)
```

Every Repository has a controller like this:

```
public ThatRepository (DataSource ds)
```

There is one master DataSource, but that is never passed to the repository. Instead it needs:

```
MasterDataSource.WithUser ( httpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name )
```

Are there any DI frameworks for WebAPI that would support this out of the box?

Comment: [Dependency-injection anti-pattern: Injecting runtime data into components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99)

Comment: If I'm not injecting run-time data, there's not any point in using a DI framework. I'll just build a single context root and call it done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could use almost every DI container for such a purpose, by registering current `HttpContext` (or even the current user `Identity`) inside the container and then injecting it for constructing your `DataSource` instance.

Here it is a simple solution using `HttpContext` in SimpleInjector (you may easily port the code to any DI framework you like):

```
container.Register<HttpContextBase>(() =>
    new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), 
    Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register<DataSource>(() =>
    {
        var httpContext = container.GetInstance<HttpContextBase>();
        return MasterDataSource.WithUser(httpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name);
    }, 
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the `HttpContext` behind an interface you control and have your DI container of choice resolve that when needed.

```
public interface ICurrentUser {
    string Name{get;}
}
```

A concrete implementation of that interface can look like...

```
public class UserProvider : ICurrentUser {
    HttoContextBase httpContext;
    UserProvider(){
        httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    }
    public string Name { 
        get{ return httpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty; } 
    }
}
```

You register your interface/contract with your DI container and resolve it when needed for your `DataSource`.

```
public void SomeSetupMethod(ICurrentUser user) {
    MasterDataSource.WithUser(user?.Name);
}
```